# How can I defeat Crowe's team in Westmor of Chapter 8?

Tags: bravely-default

In Chapter 8 after defeating all the Asterisk Holder world wide final Side Quest pops up in Eternia Central Command (Westmor), here you fight specialized teams on your way to the Council of Six's chamber.

I am up to Black Mage Ominas Crowe's team (with Sage Yulyana, Dr Qada and Summoner Mephilia Venus) who wipes me out in one turn before i get a chance to cure anyone because Dr Qada makes me vulnerable to Fire before i am pelted by Crowe's Fire Magic and Mephilia summoning of Prometheus Sin.

Is there a way i can defeat them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cheap dirty method which in Easy and Normal should kill off the entire team in one turn (on Hard you may need Bravery Seconds, however this have not being tested).

You need your entire party as Dark Night Ninja - these are Ninja who have the Dark Art's ability as their second ability. You need to level up the Dark Night to learn *Gloom* and *Dark Nebula* (Dark Night Level 11). Switching them to this combination will do 2 things:

1. Ninjas give the biggest innate speed boost, allowing the party to get their attacks in quicker
2. Ninjas have innate Duel Wield skill

Equip every character with the 2 best weapons since this trick will end the battle in one turn. When the battle starts Brave x4 and use Dark Nebula. My party (at Level 79) did about 5,000 - 9,999 damage each attack, depending on what other abilities they had, their weapons and critical hits. After the party is finished they should have done between 80,000 - 159,984 damage to each opponent which should end the battle, so the fact that everyone is now on < 20% HP should not be a problem.

If this is too risky there is an alternative which has worked in future battles, however there is an margin of error in it. You have 3 Dark Knight Ninja's with the same set up as above and a White Mage Spiritmaster (Spiritmaster with White Magic Ability) who has the Holy One Ability (Spiritmaster Level 9), because the Ninja will act first your White Mage Spiritmaster can then use Curada, Holy One will boost it's power by x2.5 which will, most of the time, fully recover the party.

The margin of error comes from when the White Mage Spiritmaster acts, ideally you want them to act after your Dark Knight Ninja to recover the 80% HP they spent during their onslaught, but before the enemy has a chance to pick them off. The advantage to this method is that if you survive the end of the turn (and until you have 0 Braves) you can repeat the Dark Nebula x4 again later on.

(Kudos to Liz on Miiverse for coming up with the basic approach)

Answer (score 2):

So I did'nt really want to use one of those cheesy methods, so I experimented and ended up with this based on what my characters skills and job levels are:

Tiz: Vampire with Spiritism (need stillness/enigma/adaptation) and bravesuit equip

Anges: Salve Maker with White Magic (need dispel) and group cast all

Ringabel: Swordmaster with Piracy (need Free Lunch) and hawkeye/axe lore

Edea: Performer with really anything

Starting the battle with Stillness to raise BP, then Edea would "One more for you" to either Tiz and Ringabel. Repeat. Then have Tiz use Enigma and Ringabel use Free Lunch to spam-brave amped strike with Edea providing BP and repeat til that stupid turd Qada is dead. Agnes was healing and using dispel on foes to get rid of reflect because they will be stupid enough to Fira themselves. Once Qada is gone, just use Enigma and/or Adaptation and you are pretty much set to bring the pain, removing their reflect, healing/reviving, and adding BP when necessary.

Hopefully that made sense, Ive never responded to these things, but I was super excited about finally defeating this awful group I felt like sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my cheesy strategy:
4x Monk/Dark Knight with 20% physical damage, 20% speed, and Natural Talent.
Equip nothing on everyone, and on the first turn brave x4 with everyone, 3 Black Banes and a Minus Strike (doesn't matter on who).

If you're high enough level, this should do about 120000 damage to each emeny *before* the minus strikes.

This strat also barely worked on the next fight.